# Tridion DTAP Clarified - How many Content Delivery setups do I need?

Tags: tridion

I asked about developer setup for Tridion DTAP (development, test, acceptance, and production) [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166754/proper-dtap-setup-for-content-delivery), but understand the example didn't match a typical DTAP scenario.

Chris Summers explains the CM-side well in his [Fifth Tridion Environment post](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/06/The-Fifth-Environment.aspx). But for clarity, could I get help understanding the ideal setup?

### CMS environments

- D = Development
- T = Test
- A = Acceptance
- P = Production

I understand typical authors only use Production and publish from CMS Production to "Live" and "Staging." The other environments are for development.

### CD?

**Does "Live and Staging" apply to each of the other environments--does that mean 8 content delivery setups (per website)?**

And if so, where is it okay to consolidate--fewer CMS environments? Fewer target types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you should have Live and Staging in every environment - The main reason I see for this (assuming you use SiteEdit in your staging environment only), is to validate that SiteEdit syntax is output only to the correct targets.

It is not uncommon to have code which checks which target you are publishing to, and alters the output accordingly. If this is the case, it is essential to test with the same collection of targets and target types that the production environment has.

Additional reasons for having matching target setups in the lower environments may include the need to validate security models where you give rights to deploy to certain targets to distinct users or groups, and if you are using the "Minimal Level of Approval" feature on targets when combined with workflow.

Comment: Close call, @RamG, but I'll upvote both but accept Chris's answer for the details.

Comment: Yes, you would need Staging and Live targets on each environment - especially to be able to develop, test and accept customizations like custom Resolvers that require specific target types, SiteEdit, Workflow, and maybe some others.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is the model what the enterprises want and we often build this as a practice so consistent environment model is maintained across all environments.

SiteEdit/Workflow plays a big role on Staging environment and must have in all the environment if they are being used.

Can you consolidate CMS environments? obviously yes with more target types/CDs but there are implications on your DTAP model. (e.g.; combining CMS for QA & UAT ).

Comment: Excellent point on SiteEdit and Workflow. I agree enterprises (customer's decision makers) definitely _need_ and probably _want_ the full setup, but also I've seen IT balk at what they perceive to be double the work. This is getting easier though with VMs and dynamic setups (DD4T).

Comment: Whilst I do agree with Ram and Chris, in reality I've had more experience with a single target on D/T/A so the same site is used for SiteEdit use. This target is then renamed as "Staging" once setup on P and a new "Live" target created alongside. Not done much with Workflow (yet!).